# check if map markers are within selected bounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with various markers and i need to be able to draw a rectangle on the map and select the markers which are within the rectangle bounds.

So far i have found some great info here: [How to get markers inside an area selected by mouse drag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927413/how-to-get-markers-inside-an-area-selected-by-mouse-drag)

I have implemented the keymapzoom plugin ok. like so

```
    $('#dispatcher').gmap3({action:'get'}).enableKeyDragZoom({
        boxStyle: {
          border: "dashed black",
          //backgroundColor: "red",
          opacity: 0.5
        },
        paneStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "gray",
          opacity: 0.2
        }
  });
var dz = $('#dispatcher').gmap3({action:'get'}).getDragZoomObject();
google.maps.event.addListener(dz, 'dragend', function (bnds) {
  alert(bnds);
});
```

This gives me the following
((**lat,long**),(**lat,long**)) format from the alert(bnds);

I need to know how i can now check if any markers are within this?

I already have an object that is storing the markers for another reason. like:

```
    markers[name] = {};
    markers[name].lat = lati;
    markers[name].lng = longi;
```

which might be useful?

I don't understand how to use the GLatLngBounds and containsLatLng(latlng:GLatLng) as suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Box/Rectangle Draw Selection in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976196/box-rectangle-draw-selection-in-google-maps)

This was my solution..

```
     google.maps.event.addListener(dz, 'dragend', function(e) { //important listener          
      for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){ // looping through my Markers Collection       
        if(e.contains(markers[i].position))
            console.log("Marker"+ i +" - matched");
        }         
     });
```

Answer (score 11):

Your question is tagged with the v3 version of the Maps API, so I'll assume you are using that version (which you should as v2 is deprecated). Note that some classes and methods are named different than in your question.

Bounds are represented with the [`LatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) class. You can perform the `contains` method on an instance of that class to determine if a point lies within those bounds.

If you have an object with all your markers, you can loop through them and check each marker, for example:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
for (var a in markers) {
    if (bounds.contains(new google.maps.LatLng(markers[a].lat, markers[a].lng)) {
        // marker is within bounds
    }
}
```

On a side note, I would store the LatLng object in the markers object when creating them. That way you don't have to create them wherever you need.

Comment: yes its v3 api. thanks for your reply Peter. so should i be able to use var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(bnds); ?

Comment: The constructor takes 2 arguments: southwest and northeast. Just click the link I provided.

Comment: i see, so how can i get the sw and ne arguments from my bnds output?

Comment: You draw a rectangle on the map, right? Seems like you can use that data to calculate the lat/lng of each point, Google it.

Comment: what about other polygons, a hexagon, or a circle?

Comment: @Raymond LatLngBounds is used for rectangles only (the doc says "represents a rectangle in geographical coordinates"). There is also a [Polygon class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon) for which you can use the [Poly](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly) utility library.