# Categorize current location based on predefined zones

Tags: google-maps, cordova

I have divided the map of india into 4 zones. These zones are rectangular and i have stored the latitude and longitude of the 4 corners of the region.

What I want to do is based on the current location of the user which I am able to get categorize him to one of the zones. Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if map markers are within selected bounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229711/check-if-map-markers-are-within-selected-bounds)

Answer (score 0):

See the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229711/check-if-map-markers-are-within-selected-bounds). You need to check whether or not the coordinates of the current location are within the bounds objects you have created for each of your four areas.