# filter markers that are within google map bounds

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function (event) 
                            {
                                 var ne = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
                                //northeast lat and long

                                var sw = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
                               //southwest lat and long

                                 var x = document.getElementById('hdnControl').value;
                               // x contains all the markers retrived from database 


                              // code part to filter markers withing bounds

                            }
```

var x contains all the markers and I want to place markers that are within bounds.how can i filter the markers which are within bounds? 
any help will be appreciated

```
  x contains value as
[
 {"Latitude":19.2094000000,"Longitude":73.0939000000},
 {"Latitude":19.2244070000,"Longitude":73.1545760000},
 {"Latitude":19.1659242536,"Longitude":82.2436523438},
 {"Latitude":18.3336694458,"Longitude":80.4309082031}
]

//as it has been serialized with
//dt is datatable retrived from database
JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        var Result = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      select new
                      {
                          Latitude = c.Field<Decimal>("Latitude"),
                          Longitude = c.Field<Decimal>("Longitude")
                      }).ToList();

        hdnControl.Value = oSerializer.Serialize(Result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Data) object comes with a `contains()` method which takes a LatLng point and returns true if the point happens to be within the bounds, or false if outside.

Here's a sample code to point if the marker is within the bound:

```
function check_is_in_or_out(marker){
return map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition());
}
```

Here's a related SO ticket which discuss how to use `bounds.contains()`: [check if map markers are within selected bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229711/check-if-map-markers-are-within-selected-bounds)